# When to use rvalue reference

Tags: c++, parameters, rvalue-reference, rvalue

So basically my question is: When should I use an rvalue reference?
In this example, I'm working on a logger class (it just logs things to the console...). I have different functions to log messages on different log levels. They take in an std::string as a parameter. Should I have two versions of each function, the first one for a "normal" reference and the second for an rvalue reference?

```cpp
namespace lnr
{
    class logger
    {
    public:
        logger(const string& name);
        logger(const string&& name);
        ~logger() = default;

        const void trace(const string& message) const;
        const void trace(const string&& message) const;
        const void info(const string& message) const;
        const void info(const string&& message) const;
        const void warn(const string& message) const;
        const void warn(const string&& message) const;
        const void error(const string& message) const;
        const void error(const string&& message) const;


    private:
        const string name;
    };
}
```

Because it is quiete common to log something with both

```cpp
logger.trace("Hello");
```

and

```cpp
std::string error_message = "...";
logger.error(error_message);
```

But having every function two times is really weird and it also seems a bit unnecessary...

Comment: there is no need to rvalue catch a const parameter, just treat it as const lvaue ref and everything still good.

Comment: rvalue const reference has practically no use cases, because a const ref does the same thing. instead, rvalue are passed by non-const reference, and so you can move them , and for example, using vector, moving a vector means something like "swapping a pointer", where copying it means copy every element

Answer (score 7):

If you're taking in a string that you're going to copy and store, you're better off not taking references at all: **take a value**.

```
struct T
{
    T(std::string str) : m_str(std::move(str)) {}

private:
    std::string m_str;
};
```

Now, the person making the `T` (hah!) can either just pass in an existing string that'll get copied without affecting the original string… or they can `std::move` a string they don't need any more.

So, if you need a copy, you just get one copy; if you don't, you just get a string of moves. Nice and cheap!

---

If you're taking in a string just to use in that function, i.e. you're not *taking ownership*, there's no reason to bother about any of this. Just accept a nice old-fashioned `const std::string&`.

```
void foo(const std::string& str)
{
   std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

---

Though there are some rare exceptions, I generally *only* have a function take an rvalue reference when it's a move constructor or a move assignment operator. We do that because the semantics of the language's "overload resolution" rules are built around moves working that way (and because having a possible copy, like in my first example, is not desirable when we have no "target" object to put it in).

You will also see things like `auto&&`, or `T&&` where `T` is a template parameter. This is not actually an rvalue reference, but a so-called *forwarding reference*, which has uses when you want to pass along the rvalue-ness of an argument where possible, depending on the template context.

Comment: Is it worth taking `str` by value when we could decide that we no longer want to store `str`, but use it instead.

Comment: @kaveish If you change your mind, that's fine, change your mind; turn it into a reference.

Comment: And if you're going to say "but then you have to change the interface" - well, that's fine. If the semantics of your function have changed _that_ much, the users of it **should** be reviewing their uses of it anyway. Ideally you would instead create a new function with a different name to avoid regressions. Don't change the meaning of functions. [Mark the "old" ones deprecated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated), and eventually remove them.

Comment: I see what you're saying, and in general I would pass by value if I need to store the input, or use `const &` otherwise. But if this class is part of an interface to my library, I would prefer to provide constructors for both `const std::string &` and `std::string &&` to avoid future interface changes. If I didn't need to store the input I would only provide `const std::string &` and add the rvalue reference later if it becomes necessary.